# Python: How to display the calculated MD5 value in my browser?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, md5

I was given this Python code that would calculate an MD5 value for any phrase:

```
import md5
md5.new("Nobody inspects the spammish repetition").digest()
```

(The phrase here is: "Nobody inspects the spammish repetition")

What I want to do is display this value in my browser. How do I do it in Python?

I tried all these variants, none of them worked:

```
import md5
show = md5.new("Nobody inspects the spammish repetition").digest()
print show

import md5
print md5.new("Nobody inspects the spammish repetition").digest()

import md5
md5.new("Nobody inspects the spammish repetition").digest()
print md5

import md5
md5.new("Nobody inspects the spammish repetition").digest()
print md5.new
```

---

update A:

By now (Monday, 5 April 2010, 07:19:35 GMT) I have received two answers from Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams and from Ji. Both have suggested pretty much the same thing. I have tried Ji's code, but it didn't work. Here is the screen shot of the error lines I received: 
[image]
<sub>(source: [narod.ru](http://roundcan.narod.ru/screenshot_of_MD5-display_problem.jpg))</sub>

(I believe you need to right click on the image and choose "View the Image" to see it in a bigger size)

Comment: Your screenshot image is inaccessible.

Comment: Really?! How come?!! In my browser it's displayed just fine. Please, check out its URL then: http://roundcan.narod.ru/screenshot_of_MD5-display_problem.jpg the image is located (published) there.

Comment: You are obviously *already* using some sort of web framework, in order to get the traceback you see above. Jj and Ignacio assumed you weren't, so advised web.py and/or Django. But what are you actually using?

Comment: @ Daniel Roseman
Hello, Daniel!!!! To tell you the truth, I myself don't know whether or not I am using a framework. I don't even know what it is! My knowledge about Python is almost zero. The reason why I chose to learn Python is because I was advised here to use it on Google App Engine. And the reason why I came to Google App Engine was because I needed a web service that would periodically run a code that would log into my accounts on Yahoo and eBay a check them for some changes. Here I was advised to use "Google App Engine", so I went there and

Comment: @ Daniel Roseman (2):
downloaded "Google App Engine SDK" and downloaded and installed Python 2.5 from http://www.python.org/ . I didn't download or install anything else besides that. So, judging from what i have just described, can You tell that I already have a framework installed on my computer? If not, please, tell me how I could check that. Thank You.

Comment: @ Daniel Roseman (3): Hello, Daniel!!! I am sorry, I just discovered that since I have downloaded "Google App Engine", I am already using a kind of framework, which is called "webapp". Look, this is what GAE tutorial ( http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingwebapp.html ) says: "App Engine includes a simple web application framework of its own, called webapp. The webapp framework is already installed in the App Engine environment and in the SDK, so you do not need to bundle it with your application code to use it. We

Comment: @ Daniel Roseman (4): will use webapp for the rest of this tutorial." But now I wonder, if I am already using a framework, how come the code that Ji gave me here (see below) still didn't work? Do You have any idea?

Comment: @brilliant, you need to install whichever web framework you desire to use in order to use it. The sample code depends on webpy. You have to install it in your computer first. Read the installation instructions http://webpy.org/install

The error in your screenshot is telling you that "web" (that is the webpy framework) isn't installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to display the hexdigest in your browser you need to have some sort of web framework (in this case in python) that handles all the web serving for you.

Here's an example using [web.py](http://webpy.org) (I've copied the default example and adjusted for the md5). But you can use any other framework out there

```
import web
from md5 import md5

urls = (
    '/(.*)', 'digest' 
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

class digest:        
    def GET(self):
        return md5("Nobody inspects the spammish repetition").hexdigest()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Thank You, Ji, but I just tried Your code and it didn't work. Am I doing something wrong? Please refer to "Update A" above to see the screen shot of my problem.

Comment: @brilliant: The `web` module won't be used unless you're already using web.py.

Comment: Thank You, Ignacio!!! Can You, please, give me some clue as to how I could start using it?

Comment: Nope, never used it. I use WSGI or Django myself. http://wsgi.org/ http://djangoproject.com/

Comment: @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: Oh, Lord!!! It has become so complicated! Finally, I have arrived at the necessity of getting myself familiarized with another new big name - Django! I wonder, why does it have to be so complicated? Is it really so hard to just display the calculated MD5 value in my browswer using just Python?

Comment: Yeah it's a fairly complicated thing to listen for HTTP connections, connect those requests to your application in a consistent way, configure that application to enter your code at a specific point, and then take the return of your code and make it suitable for a web browser. That's why people use frameworks instead of writing these things themselves.

Answer (score 3):

`.hexdigest()` is what you want.

Comment: Thank You, Ignacio. I guess You are suggesting the same thing Ji suggested here right after You (see below). Something went wrong with his code on my computer, and I don't know why (please refer to the "Update A" section above to see the details from the error-message screeen shot).